# Why is my callback not working for JSONP data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services, jsonp

I am not able to get the feed for the following data. I know something is wrong with the way I am specifying the data for ajax. below is what I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                dataType:'jsonp',
                url:'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/tags/?callback=?',
                success:function(data) {
                    alert(data.tags[0].name.length)
                },
                error:function() {
                    alert("Sorry, I can't get the feed");   
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

I am getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: invalid label [Break On This Error]
>
> "total": 31987,

**As per TJ, I am just getting a raw JSON file. Now what do I need to make this as my server sends a JSON request.**

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the response to `http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/tags/?callback=foo`, you'll see that it's JSON, not JSONP. According to the documentation at [api.stackoverflow.com](http://api.stackoverflow.com), you need to add the `jsonp` query parameter to get JSONP: `http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/tags/?jsonp=foo`

With jQuery, which wants to control the name of the callback for maximum reliability, you'd use the `jsonp` option to tell it what the name of that parameter should be (and don't put it in the URL, jQuery will do that):

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    jsonp: "jsonp",
    url:'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/tags/',
    success:function(data) {
        alert(data.tags[0].name.length)
    },
    error:function() {
        alert("Sorry, I can't get the feed");   
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually I got it working for stackoverflow feed, but when I use this on my feed from a different site, I still get the Invalid label syntax error. how do  I make my server return encodedjson data. lke how SO does above. Below still wont work.

 $.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp:'jsonp',
    url: 'http://www.exampledoman.com/demos/file.json?jsonp=?',
    type : 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
    $.each(data["it......rest of the code

Comment: @Mike: The server has to explicitly support JSONP. Your example URL looks like it's just fetching a file, no server-side processing, in which case it can't do JSONP because to do JSONP (properly) you use the callback name specified in the request. The core concept of JSONP is: The caller says what function name should be used, and the response is `theFunctionName(` followed by what would otherwise be JSON if it were allowed by the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) followed by `);` -- e.g., instead of actual JSON, it's *JavaScript*, making a function call with an object literal.

Comment: how do I make my server support JSONP.